# Gridview layout issue in android

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview

I have this layout for a gridview which i'm using to display some images and texts that i take from a JSON object. I created this gridview so that i ahows only 2 columns and it was working fine.  But when i wanted to change it to 3 columns my gridview images become so small and textview is shown like a vertical line. Why does it work for android:numColumns="2"  and not for android:numColumns="3"?

gridview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@color/grey"
    android:id="@+id/theater_fragment" >

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
        android:numColumns="3"
        android:verticalSpacing="5dp" >

    </GridView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

single gridview item

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >


<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_theater"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"/>


      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/theater_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/image_theater"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textStyle="bold" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please fix the imageview size like height and widht

Comment: i fixed it.still no change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: not quiet the answer.but i got an idea from your answer and now i got my answer.thanx